# Nose collect tests in a directory

Tags: python, nose

I am trying to collect all the tests in a particular directory with nose from a python script.

My directory structure looks like

```
script.py
test_dir/
  testsetA/testA1.py
           testA2.py
           __init__.py
  testsetB/testB1.py
           testB2.py
           __init__.py
  testsetC/...
```

From script.py, I run nose like

```
args = ['-w test_dir/testsetA/', '--collect-only']   
nose.run(argv=args)
```

The problem is, it seems to collect all the tests in testsetA, B, C and so on, rather than just the two in testsetA like I would expect.  I can probably use the --with-id option and figure out which tests are in testsetA, but I'd rather nose just collect the tests from the directory I specified.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split the `-w` from the directory:

```
args = ['-w', 'test_dir/testsetA/', '--collect-only']
```

Otherwise `nose` will think that `'-w test_dir/testsetA/` is a single argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 3.X, you should write it like this:

```
args = ['--py3where', 'test_dir/testsetA/', '--collect-only']
```